# How Insert DateTime Vales into Mysql Databse ...from the front end application.But User Gives Date only

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I am new developer in .net,I Have requirement..like this ,when user pick date from date picker not time only date he/she pick up,then click insert that time ,i want insert that **date** and **time** is  into Column exist with name "EnterdDate"  data type is "DATETIME".
by default 00:00:00  is stored in the Time format I don't want to be stroed that values I want store The at the Time insertion MySql Server Time.
**ex:user 12/03/2013 ->insert->click 
presently assume server time is 13:00:00** 
**i want insert This Date value --> 2013-03-12 13:00:00   ok for me.**
**i don't need the DateAndTime like is :2013-03-12 00:00:00    not Ok for me.**

please give me best answer any body now the above one .

Comment: from the "front-end application"... well, that could be anything. Please ask specific questions and provide enough context to understand your problem! or just try clicking on the "insert DateTime Vale" button at the bottom right - it is flashing in green sometimes :)

Comment: If you're getting the current time from the server, why aren't you getting the current date from the server?

Comment: This question is tagged for [tag:sql-server]. Does it really have anything to do with *Microsoft SQL Server*, or is it only about MySQL?

Comment: I would use my front end application to append the current time to the date and send that to the db.  My front ends are usually written in ColdFusion and it's simply easier to do it that way.

Answer (score 0):

This is for SQL server as you have tagged SQL Server in your question , you can use corresponding Mysql date functions .

Get current time from GETDATE() by

```
convert(varchar(11),getdate(),108)
```

this will return a string in format

```
18:33:03.000
```

Add this string to selected date and convert the resultant string to DateTime datatype

```
declare @selectedDate varchar(11)

set @selectedDate = '04/25/2013'
select convert(datetime,@SelectedDate +' ' + convert(varchar(11),getdate(),108))
```

This returns a datetime value

```
2013-04-25 18:33:03.000
```